# Which connector system for serial row of PCB plus cables?

Tags: pcb, connector

i have a series of PCB modules with signal in and signal out that need to be connected via cables. 
I want to find a connector system that uses male/female on both PCB as well as cables so i can make sure that the user can only hook up signal out to signal in via cables. It would look like "PCB Male" <-> "Cable Female" <-> "Cable Male" <-> "PCB Female".
The board connector needs to have a 2.54mm pitch and preferably polarised.
Any idea which system can do that? checked JST and Molex but couln't

Comment: ordinary 2.54mm spaced pin headers can do that. male terminations on cables are not common but they are available, you'll have to use blanking plugs and skip some pins to ensure polarisation.  PCB terminations come in both types.

Answer (score 2):

IDC ribbon cables are a reasonable way to achieve this - male cable ends and female PCB connectors are less common than their gender complements and often slightly more expensive but I have never been unable to find what I was looking for.

These generally have polarisation built in which removes the need for pin skipping.